# Compile and install a C++ program using python setup.py

Tags: python, c++, virtualenv, setuptools, distutils

My Python projects depend on a C++ program. I want to create a python package that compiles and installs this program into virtual environment. The program should appear in the current PATH.

I've tried to register the source files using the `ext_modules` option, but it creates .so module. Not exactly what I need.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can run shell commands in python, this should be enough to compile the code.

```
import os
os.system ("make -C /path/to/makefile")
```

You can also run the resultant object file as a subprocess;

```
import subprocess
theCProcess = subprocess.Popen('/path/to/object/file')
```

or

```
theCProcess = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/object/file', 'some', 'extra', 'arguments'])
```

Also what do you mean by PATH? Do you mean the bash PATH variable? Normally that should remain constant as `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, you could put your binary in those directories but only if you wanted it to be available system wide.

Comment: Thanks. This question is about use of setup.py, not just Python.